# Subsquent HttpWebRequest with NetworkCredential set honors recently changed domain password

Tags: httpwebrequest, windows-authentication, networkcredentials

We gather a windows domain username and password and persist that in a cookie through a web front end.  Those credentials along with a request for specific data are on an ongoing basis ultimately passed through a WCF call hosted in windows service that itself redirects that as a new REST call to another server setup under IIS with windows auth configured.  This is done using HttpWebRequest...

```
var url = baseServerUrl + "/" + apiCall.Url;
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Timeout = 1000000;
request.Method = apiCall.HttpMethod;
bool credentialsSet = false;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiCall.Identity))
{
    // split into Domain\User\Password
    var parts = apiCall.Identity.Split('\\');
    if (parts.Length == 3)
    {
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(parts[1], parts[2], parts[0]);
        credentialsSet = true;
    }
}
// Then more code submitting the request ...
```

So if I store in the cookie domain password A, make a request through the above (which all works fine), but then change my windows domain password to B what we are finding for subsequent requests is the above code (again running as a windows service) will happily authenticate just fine when receiving and setting A on the NetworkCredential (receiving A because the cookie is still hanging around with the old password).  If we restart the service immediately any further attempts to use the HttpWebRequest and NetworkCredential with password A generate a 401.  Why are the old domain passwords honored until the restart?  How do you stop that behavior?

Comment: Just. Wow. This is such a bad idea.